80's film where guy gives his intoxicated lover a lethal injection
At the risk of giving you a bad steer, I thought the guy was James Spader, but I can't find anything in IMDB of his that sounds right. He's playing a disreputable character, I think he has a couple of lovers who he treats pretty badly, one of whom he sticks a needle into to do her in when she is already too drugged/intoxicated to put up much of a fight.
Again risking a bad steer but I thought the unfortunate girl was Anne Heche, or maybe an Arquette, but looking up their work has turned up no positive ID. I'm pretty certain the girl has cropped blond hair.
I saw this film a long time ago so it is certainly last century; I'd put my money on 1980's but it may be first half of the 90's.

Sounds similar to the scene in Pulp Fiction where John Travolta sticks a needle of adrenalin into Uma Thurman's chest

In The Juror (1996), Alec Baldwin forces Anne Heche to take a fatal drug overdose when she is already very intoxicated, but it was pills, not an injection.

Bingo, well done mate.
